# How do I create a regular expression to disallow backslash

Tags: c#, regex

I am having trouble creating a regular expression to disallow the following four characters and limit the size:

/
#
?
\

What I currently have is:

```
Regex regex = new Regex("^[^/\\#?]{0,1024}$", RegexOptions.Compiled);
if (!regex.IsMatch("\\"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Bad");
}
```

All of the characters except \ are disallowed. I cannot get \ to work.

Any suggestions on how to support this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your regex is fine, `^[^/\\#?]{0,1024}$`.

**However**, in C# backslash is an escape character, so a C# `"\\"` is a single backslash.
Hence for each backslash in your regex, you have to backslash *again* for C#:

```
Regex regex = new Regex("^[^/\\\\#?]{0,1024}$", RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

Alternatively, you can use a raw string, meaning backslashes in C# strings remain backslashes (note the `@` symbol):

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^[^/\\#?]{0,1024}$", RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

Answer (score 2):

You were close, you need to escape the backslash:

> `^[^/\\#?]{0,1024}$`

Even though you do not need to escape special characters inside a character class you do need to escape the escape character itself.

Answer (score 1):

Try two forward slashes.

```
^[^/\\#?]{0,1024}$
```

In C++, the forward slash is reserved for escape characters, like `\n`.  To make a literal forward slash, use `\\`.